# ShouldSerialize pattern and DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

Is there a way to get the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern working with `DataContractSerializer`?

Here is a small example:

I have a simple class `Person` which looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
  [DataMember]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public bool ShouldSerializeFirstName()
  {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName);
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public bool ShouldSerializeLastName()
  {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName);
  }

  public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
  }
  public Person(string firstName)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
  }
  public Person()
  {
  }
}
```

`FirstName` or `LastName` should only be serialized if they are not null or empty. This works with `XmlSerializer` but `DataContractSerializer` seems to ignore the `ShouldSerialize`pattern. The `*Specified` pattern also doesn't work.

I'm creating two different Xml files. One with DataContractSerializer, one with XmlSerializer:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add (new Person("John", "Doe"));
persons.Add (new Person("Carl"));

DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer (typeof (List<Person>));
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\test1.xml", settings))
{
  serializer.WriteObject (writer, persons);
}

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof (List<Person>));
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create (@"c:\text2.xml", settings);
xmlSerializer.Serialize (xmlWriter, persons);
xmlWriter.Close();
```

The output of the file `test1.xml` (DataContractSerializer) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XmlSerialization">
  <Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Carl</FirstName>
    <LastName i:nil="true" />
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

The output of file `test2.xml` (XmlSerializer) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Carl</FirstName>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, ShouldSerialize* does not work with datacontract serializer. It is useless in the Kevin answer. You can remove it.
Unfortunatly, the code given only work if you handle null value.

Here is a more generic solution: It returns null value depending of a given condition.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
      private string firstName;
      [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
      public string FirstName
      {
        get
        {
            //Put here any condition for serializing
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) ? null : firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the IsRequired attribute on the DataMember:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
  [DataMember(IsRequired = False, EmitDefaultValue = False)]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work. The properties still get serialized altough they are null.

Comment: Add EmitDefaultValue = false, to that list, too (changed in the SSCE, as well).

Comment: The solution is not exactly equivalent to ShouldSerialize*(). With the latter, I am able to explicitly write the value, even if it is the default and I can suppress values not equal to the default, everything based on some other vaiable during runtime. +1 anyway, as it is helpful (and not your fault that we have such a mess with all those different serialization technologies and concepts, produced by one software vendor).

Comment: ShouldSeralize* does not work with DataContractSerializer.  This answer is misleading, the ShouldSeralize method is never called.  The only reason this "works" is because the logic in `ShouldSerializeFirstName()` is redundant to the functionality provided by the parameters to the DataMember attribute.