# C# - Skip serialization of a base class property?

Tags: c#, inheritance, datacontractserializer, datamember

I searched for a while and found no answer.

I'm using the **DataContractSerializer**. Is it possible to make it skip the serialization of a base property?

Base class:

```
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public virtual int BaseProperty{ get; set; }

    //...
    //Many other properties with [DataMember]

}
```

Derived class:

```
[DataContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // *** NO [DataMember] here***
    public override int BaseProperty
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Does not apply");          
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Does not apply");          
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I see the error message:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Error in line 1 position 248...Expecting element 'BaseProperty'.
```

Comment: that doesn't make much sense. if `BaseClass` needs it, why skip it.

Comment: There are a dozen of common properties in the base class and there are derived classes other than the one shown. There is a single property in the base that I'd like to skip for this particular derived class (but not the rest).

Comment: try [ScriptIgnore] atrribute;[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization)

Comment: *IgnoreDataMember* only works on types without *[DataContract]*. My derived class needs that.

Comment: Is it out of the question that you override the built in serializer and serilize by hand?

Comment: Instead of `override` try to hide base class member and use `new int BaseProperty` in the derived class

Comment: Take the field out of base class.  Make a sub-base, or whatever you want to call it, add the field to this class.  Have your single class inherit from base, so it is on same level as sub-base if you visualize the inheritance as a tree, and all others inherit from sub-base.

Comment: Not really.  `DataContractSerializer` doesn't even support the `ShouldSerialize` pattern; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11394587/3744182) for details and workarounds.  Possibly adding `EmitDefaultValue = false` to the base class would meet your needs?  Your best bet may be to use a [serialization surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx) to inject an appropriate [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) into your object graph during serialization.